# Blender deforms mesh wher pose mode as rest (and undo after)

Tags: mesh, pose-mode

Not sure if I phrased the title correctly, sorry.

Blender 2.93.5.
What actions did I take:

- Change the character's pose to T-pose (raised arms 40 degrees)
- Apply as rest pose
- Copied the mesh (and armature)
- Reverted changes (to state before T-pose)
- Pasted the mesh (as a new object) and lower arms (from T-pose)

In the image, the body is on the right and the arm is in a lowered position.

[image]

It can be seen that the vertices have changed their position.
Yes, the model is not ideal, but why did this happen and how to avoid this situation or is it normal?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is your problem but if you change the default pose, it won't change the default mesh shape, you also need to give it a T pose

Comment: I have an object with armature and mesh (and weights)
I selected the armature, turned on the pose mode, changed the angle of the arms and applied it as a rest pose. That is, the mesh was deformed (or whatever it is called, I'm new to blender).
The question is that applying the reverse actions - I get a different result.

Comment: Yoiu first need to bring back the armature to its default pose, and change the mesh so that it matches the pose